# Caching images from Stream response in Flutter from Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, image-caching, flutter-streambuilder

In my flutter application with firebase database, I am using **stream response** to get data from firebase firestore. Following is code of fetching

```
Stream<List<PostEntity>> readPosts(PostEntity post) {
    final postCollection = firebaseFirestore
        .collection(FirebaseConstants.posts)
        .orderBy("createAt", descending: true);
    return postCollection.snapshots().map((querySnapshot) =>
        querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => PostModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList());
  }
```

Then I am converting stream response to list of posts.

```
Future<void> readPosts({ required PostEntity post})async{
    emit(PostLoading());
    try {
      final streamResponse = readPostsUsecase.call(post);
      streamResponse.listen((posts) {
        emit(PostLoaded(posts: posts));
      });
    }on SocketException catch (_) {
      emit(PostFailure());
    }
    catch (_) {
      emit(PostFailure());
    }
  }
```

It is returning Posts data containing link to Posturl, which is also stored in Firebase Storage.
I am using **"cached_network_image"** to cache images, but it starts loading after I scroll, means caching is not working properly.
Though when I turn off the internet, Cached images already gets load, but why they starts loading when internet is on.
Here I am displaying image:

```
return CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: photoUrl,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, progress) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                value: progress.progress,
              ),
            );
          },
          errorWidget: (context, url, progress) {
            return Image.asset(
              "assets/images/default-user.png",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            );
          },
        );
```

I want these images to be properly cached and after loading first time they should not load every other time. How do i do it?

Comment: The images are being cached correctly. I think the problem is the CachedNetworkImage widget gets recreated when scrolling, so it keeps on loading as a new widget. Issue could be how you are triggering the event to fetch the images, is it in the build method?

Comment: I am calling read post method of cubit in build method, using 

BlocProvider<PostCubit>(
              create: (context) =>
                  di.sl<PostCubit>().. **readPosts(post: PostEntity())**,
              child: BlocBuilder<PostCubit, PostState>(
                builder: (context, postState) {

This is called in build method, then listview.builder is used to display all the posts.

Comment: Try moving the BlocProvider<PostCubit>( create: (context) => di.sl<PostCubit>().. readPosts(post: PostEntity()) call one level up, in the previous page before navigating to the list page. So the readPosts method only gets called once. Not on every rebuild.

Or move it to initState() method.